# WCF error returning a List of objects with an inherited object as a part of the list

Tags: .net, wcf, inheritance

I have a WCF project and an other porject containing domain clases, on my WCF I have references to this project. On domain project I have two clases
"Pack" and "SpecialPack" the last inherits from first.

If I execute a method who return a List of "Pack" the WCF works fine,
If I execute a method who return a List of "SpecialPack" this also works fine, but
If i execute a method who return a List of "Pack" with a "SpecialPack" inside as an item of the list, the WCF throws an exeption.

What is the problem? 
I have data contracts and data members for serealization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add known type to your base class:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SpecialPack))]
public class Pack 
{
}
```